# Prevent Form Close

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using Access 2007 and have the following code in the close event:

```
If [field1] = "" and [field2] = "" then
       Msgbox " You must enter a value in either field 1 or field 2 "
       Cancel = false
Else
       Cancel = true
End If
```

I am trying to prevent the user from disregarding the message and closing the form via the close X button and saving the record. There have been some previous threads about this but I am unable to figure out the exact syntax.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You probably must check for Null:

```
Cancel = IsNull([field1] & [field2])

If Cancel = True Then
   Msgbox "You must enter a value in either field 1 or field 2."
End If
```